# Array PopFront Method C++

Tags: c++

Trying not to lose it here. As you can see below I have assigned intFrontPtr to point to the first cell in the array. And intBackPtr to point to the last cell in the array...:

```
bool quack::popFront(int& nPopFront)
{   
    nPopFront = items[top+1].n;
    if ( count >= maxSize ) return false;
    else
    {
        items[0].n  = nPopFront;
        intFrontPtr = &items[0].n;
        intBackPtr  = &items[count-1].n;
    }
    for (int temp; intFrontPtr < intBackPtr ;)
    {
         ++intFrontPtr;
         temp = *intFrontPtr;
        *intFrontPtr = temp;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the else statement I'm simply reassigning to ensure that my ptrs are where I want them. For some reason I'm popping off the back instead of off the front.

Anyone care to explain?

Comment: There is something wrong with you code. `nPopFront` is never used.

Comment: not using     nPopFront..is that the problem?

Comment: I have used it, and it still tries to return more than once.

Comment: I get like absolutely no help

Comment: You're not making any sense. We don't know the definition of stack. The definition of stack::popFront just looks weird. You always return true, use recursion, and you don't use the reference nPopFront at all. What exactly is popFront supposed to do?

Comment: why don't you use std::dequeue<item> or something instead? The code above isn't a joy to read, in fact I think I need to go home and lie down now.

Comment: You're code is a bit confusing:

1) Using both top and count; is top the offset of the first element in the stack?

2) The for loop to copy data in pushback doesn't do anything it just reassigns data to where it already was in the array 

3) temp doesn't seem to match the type stored in the array.

4) The title of the question doesn't seem related to the code you've posted

You'll get better answers if you can upload the whole class somewhere and give a detailed explanation of what it should do.

Comment: Whats the type of 'items'? Let's see that structure and declaration. Same with the other object variables you are using. There's not enough here to figure out the problem.

Comment: It appears the edited form of the question, i.e. without recursion, has been asked again by lampshade - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678924/popfront-delimma-c/1678997#1678997.

Comment: @Troubadour: Basically, the guy's been asking the same question over and over for about three weeks now. He doesn't give enough information to make sense of the code he pastes, doesn't answer any questions shot back at him for clarification, and complains about getting no help.

Comment: The suspect that s/he is just trolling is legitimate; in 11 months: 77 Questions (I gloss over content of these), 6 Answers (all to his own questions) and now s/he promising 250 points in this game of "reputation" (which is a little bit ridiculous in itself) when he has only 115.

Comment: @lampshade, you should take the effort to answer the questions of the people trying to help you. It is rather rude to ask a question time and time again. This is bad for the site, bad for your reputation and it won't help anybody, and surely not you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if I;m guessing right you're trying to 'pop' the 1st element of the array (`items[0]`) into the `nPopFront` int reference, then move all the subsequent elements of the array over by one so that the 1st element is replaced by the 2nd, the 2nd by the 3rd, and so on. After this operation, the array will contain one less total number of elements.

Not having the full declaration of the `quack` class makes most of the following guesswork, but here goes:

I'm assuming that `item[0]` represents the 'front' of your array (so it's the element you want 'popped').

I'm also assuming that 'count` is the number of valid elements (so item[count-1] is the last valid element, or the 'back' of the array).

Given these assumptions, I'm honestly not sure what `top` is supposed to represent (so I might be entirely wrong on these guesses).

Problem #1:  your `nPopFront` assignment is reversed, it should be:

```
nPopFront = items[0].n;
```

Problem #2; your `for` loop is a big no-op. It walks through the array assigning elements back to their original location.  I think you want it to look more like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < count; ++i)
{
    items[i-1].n = items[i].n;  // move elements from back to front
}
```

Finally, you'll want to adjust `count` (and probably `top` - if you need it at all) before you return to adjust the new number of elements in the data structure. The whole thing might look like:

```
bool quack::popFront(int& nPopFront)
{   
    if ( count >= maxSize ) return false;
    if ( count == 0 ) return false; // nothing to pop

    nPopFront = items[0].n;
    intFrontPtr = &items[0].n;      // do we really need to maintain these pointers?
    intBackPtr  = &items[count-1].n;

    for (int i = 1; i < count; ++i)
    {
        items[i-1].n = items[i].n;  // move elements from back to front
    }

    count -= 1;     // one less item in the array
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The original question seems to be that you don't understand why the function popFront returns 3 times when there are 3 elements?

If that's the case, I think you are missing the point of recursion.

When you make a recursive call, you are calling the same function again, basically creating a new stack frame and jumping back to the same function. So if there are 3 elements, it will recurse by encountering the first element, encountering the second element, encountering the third element, returning from the third encounter, returning from the second encounter, and returning from the first encounter (assuming you are properly consuming your array, which you don't appear to be).

The current function cannot return until the recursive call has iterated, thus it may appear to return from the last element before the second, and the second before the first.

That is [how recursion works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Recursion_in_computer_science).

I wasn't able to make sense of your example, so I whipped one up real fast:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool popfront(int* ptr_, int* back_) {
    cerr << ptr_[0] << endl;
    if(ptr_ != back_) {
        popfront(++ptr_, back_);
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
   int ar[4] = {4,3,2,1};
   popfront(ar, ar + 3);
   return 0;
}
```

That's not great, but it should get the point across.

Comment: Reread my explaination (the large paragraph explains why it returns more than once). I fully expect every recursive call to return at some point, thus you will see it returning more than once. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Fibonacci

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use a std::list?

That makes it really to pop from either end using pop_front or pop_back.  You can also add to the front and the back.  It also has the advantage that after popping from the front (or even removing from the middle of the list) you don't have to shift anything around (The link is simply removed) which makes it much more efficient than what you are, seemingly, proposing.

Comment: I'm under the impression that this is a learning exercise, not a 'best tool for the job' question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to assign the popped value to nPopFront?

```
bool stack::popFront(int& nPopFront) 
{    
    //items[4] = {4,3,2,1} 
    if ( intFrontPtr < intBackPtr ) 
    {    
            nPopFront = *intFrontPtr; 
            ++intFrontPtr; 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool quack::popFront(int& nPopFront)
{
   if(items.n==0) throw WhateverYouUseToSignalError;
   nPopFront = items[0];
   for (int =0;i<items.n-1,++i){
      items[i]=items[i+1]
   }
   //update size of items array
}
```