# Queue + Stack C++

Tags: c++

How do u push Items to the front of the array, ( like a stack ) without starting at MAXSIZE-1? I've been trying to use the modulus operator to do so..

```
bool quack::pushFront(const int nPushFront) 
{     
    if ( count == maxSize ) // indicates a full array
    {
         return false;
     }
    else if ( count == 0 ) 
    {
        ++count;
        items[0].n = nPushFront;
        return true;
    }
     intBack = intFront;
     items[++intBack] = items[intFront];
     ++count;
     items[(top+(count)+maxSize)%maxSize].n = nPushFront;
 /*
    for ( int shift = count - 1; shift >= 0; --shift )
    {
         items[shift] = i€tems[shift-1];
    }   
     items[top+1].n = nPushFront; */
     return true;    
  }
```

"quack" meaning a cross between a queue and a stack. I cannot simply shift my elements by 1 because it is terribly inefficient. I've been working on this for over a month now. I just need some guidence to push_front by using the modulus operator...I dont think a loop is even necessary.

Its funny because I will need to print the list randomly. So if I start adding values to the MAXSIZE-1 element of my integer array, and then need to print the array, I will have garbage values..

```
not actual code:

pushFront(2);
pushFront(4);
cout << q;
```

if we started adding from the back i would get several null values.
I cannot just simply shift the array elements down or up by one.

I cant use any stls, or boosts.

Comment: Why can't you use STL, which is a standard part of C++ and has been for over a decade?

Comment: "I've been working on this for over a month now." And you will have to work much longer if you do not provide enough information and do not answer questions from others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665459/1665507#1665507 Endlessly repeated posting of the same problem without giving enough information is not going to help you.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton, If this is a homework problem, then using STL or Boost would remove any learning value to this data structures assignment.

Comment: Right. I thought I did it correctly, by shifting either left or right for the pushFront or PushBack methods. But my instructor said, "No, Not OK". So, im trying to do it another way...

Comment: It seems that I somehow need to replace the "for loop shift" for the modulo operator.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your problem is. Are you trying to implement a queue (which *also* can work as a stack, no need for your `quack`) as a [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_buffer)?

In that case, you need to save both a front and a back index. The mechanics are described in the article linked above. Pay attention to the “Difficulties” section: in particular, you need to either have an extra variable or pay attention to leave one field empty – otherwise you won’t know how to differentiate between a completely empty and a completely full queue.

Comment: I just cant get it to work correctly.. I've seen that wiki link so many times :/

Comment: @lampshade: that’s a valid point. But in this case, you *must give more information*. As you’ve already suspected, your code is the complete wrong way to tackle this but it’s unclear where your problems start. I don’t know what you want to achieve, what your member variables represent or what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems kind of silly to rule out the stl, since [`std::deque`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html) is exactly what you want.  Amortized constant time random access.  Amortized constant insert/removal time from both the front and the back.

This can be achieved with an array with extra space at the beginning and end.  When you run out of space at either end, allocate a new array with twice the space and copy everything over, again with space at both the end and the beginning.  You need to keep track of the beginning index and the end index in your class.

Comment: +1 That's the first thing that comes to mind... If there are restrictions on STL use it's probably a homework assignment though.

Comment: But if it *is* a homework assignment, then he hasn't been working on it "for over a month now." An assignment to write a ring buffer or double-ended queue would have at most a two-week deadline.

Comment: deque means double-ended queue

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you have some conflicting requirements:

1. You have to push to the head of a C++ array primitive.
2. Without shifting all of the existing elements.
3. Maintain insertion order.

Short answer: You can't do it, as the above requirements are mutually exclusive.

One of these requirements has to be relaxed.

To help you without having to guess, we need more information about what you are trying to do.